# How to Split a text into List by multiple characters

Tags: c#

Let's say i have:

```
string text = "Ivan - George ; Josh , Mike John";
```

And i want to split it by

```
" - ", " ; " , " ".
```

Normally when I want to split a text by 1 element I would use:

```
List<string> names = text.Split(" - ").ToList();
```

But now I encountered a problem where i need to split a text by multiple characters and I don't know how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> names = text.Split(
    new []{" - ", " ; ", " "}, 
    StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
```